# Download PFFile, store locally, and access Temporary NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to download a `Parse PFFile object` *(that can be either photo or video)* and store it locally with a completion block.

Once the file is completely downloaded, I then would like to access the location to which it is temporarily saved. I've researched a bit online but I'm new to Swift and didn't get very far. What is the best way to do this?

So far, I do have the URL of the PFFile, so I guess that's a start:

```
let videoFile = video.objectForKey("file") as! PFFile
let url = NSURL(string: videoFile.url!)!
```

Comment: to be clear you are trying to download video or image from parse then store on the phone right?

Comment: Store on the phone because I have to transfer it to the next viewController. So I only want to store it temporarily for that use.

Comment: what don't you load the video straight to your UI ?

Comment: Because i have multiple one after the other and loading into the UI doesn't look too great (black screen in between loading). So I'm trying to load before showing the video, then while the current video is showing, load the next one.